# Rails/Git: can't push my rails code out to the server ('~/git/myapp.git' does not appear to be a git repository)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to rails and git. I have a rails application under ..../myapp that I would like to deploy using capistrano. I followed the steps described in "Agile Web Development with Rails". To put the application under version control, I did the following:

1) Put my application under version control:

```
$ cd myapp
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit "..."
```

That all went fine, it created a .git directory under myapp/

2) Created an empty repository on the server:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/git/myapp.git
$ cd ~/git/myapp.git
$ git --bare init
$ Initialized empty Git repository in /root/git/myapp.git/
```

3) Created a public key

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@myemail.com"
$ Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
$ Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
$ The key fingerprint is:
$ d2:16:76:e0:4c:71:de:de:4b:d3:16:94:cc:d7:65:11 myemail@myemail.com

$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

4) From my application directory: created the path to the server and push the code

```
$ git remote add origin ssh://me@host/~/git/myapp.git
$ git push origin master
```

Now I'm being asked to enter my password, after that:

```
$ fatal: '~/git/myapp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It might be worth noting that this all happens on the same server, a RHEL 5.7. This is something that confuses me because I basically ssh from my server onto my server. But apparently that's how capistrano does it, even if the application_development and the svn repository are on the same physical machine.

@ manojlds:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git push origin master
$ trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'me@host' 'git-receive-pack '\''/root/git/myapp.git'\'''
```

Comment: can you do `GIT_TRACE=2 git push origin master` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: Can you try cloning the repo? And then maybe also push from from the cloned one.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. Clone the empty repository? Like git clone ~/git/myapp.git/ tells me Cloning into myapp...
done.
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository. But which one should I push now? Where is the cloned one gone?

Comment: use `git clone ssh://me@host/~/git/myapp.git .`. NOw try to add files and commit here and do `git push origin master`

Comment: Ok, I did that. It asked me to log in (so it can reach the server) but then tells me again that it's not a git repository. Should I be in the .../myapp directory when I do that? Could it be a problem that my local application directory is on the same machine as this "remote" git repository? It sort of seems odd to me to ssh into my server from my server... But then I just try to follow the steps described in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you don't want the tilde ~ in the path. I'd put the actual path in (eg /home/users/)

Comment: No, the tilde just means that it's the root directory. That's exactly where the git directory is.

Comment: @user1090153 you know tilde isnt the actual root directory right? its your home directory.. the "root" directory is `/` :P

Comment: Well, I created the repository as root. The feedback was: $ Initialized empty Git repository in /root/git/myapp.git/ If I do git remote add origin me@host:/root/git/myapp.git it's exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Tilde expansion is not the problem as not seen in the trace path

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that using a relative path  and specifying the ssh portion is causing it to break when adding origin.

Try something closer to this:

> git remote add origin user@myserver.com:/var/git/myapp.git

Comment: Doing that causes exactly the same behaviour.